# Does 石 have two dissimilar pronunciations?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

From CEDict:

```
MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ egrep "\t石\t" /Users/Admin/Downloads/cedict_1_0_ts_utf-8_mdbg.txt 
石   石   Shi2    surname Shi
石   石   dan4    dry measure for grain equal to ten dou 斗<br/>ten pecks<br/>one hundred liters
石   石   shi2    rock<br/>stone<br/>stone inscription<br/>one of the eight ancient musical instruments 八音[ba1 yin1]
```

Is the second one an error?

Is this what is meant by "variant readings" in  [How many Chinese characters have multiple readings/pronunciations in Mandarin?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16178/how-many-chinese-characters-have-multiple-readings-pronunciations-in-mandarin) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's not an error.

Any respectable dictionary will have

石   shi2

and

石   dan4

*Variant readings* refer to when one character has more than one pronunciation - based, usually, on different meanings.

Taking 石 for instance: when we're talking about rocks and stones - it is pronounced shi2; when we're talking about a specific measurement unit it is pronounced dan4.

Comment: Cool.  I knew of several that had _similar_ pronunciations, likely from linguistic evolution.  This is the first one I've seen where the pronunciations do not seem "related."

Comment: 石 dan4 is not used now, it is an ancient measurement unit. now we use metric units.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be interesting that 1 石 is 100升 (for volume), and 1 擔 is 100斤 (for mass), so perhaps that pronunciation for 石 as a unit of volume was borrowed from its counterpart 擔 in mass. That's what Wiktionary suggests.